# Show the density is an objective quantity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

I am studying the Lagrangian and Eulerian representations of quantities within the scope of fluid dynamics.

At some point I am asked to show that the density is an objective quantity, which for a scalar variable was defined as

$$\rho(x, t) = \rho'(x',t) $$

Where $x' = Q(t)x + x_0$ represents the change of reference frame, with $Q(t) \in SO(3) $.

We did a couple of exercises on this but I don't really understand what is that I know. I can't even seem to define $\rho$ in a way that opens me up for algebraic manipulations.

On a side note, in a previous exercise I showed that

$$\rho(X, t) = \frac{\rho(X, 0)}{J(X, t)}$$

where $J $ is the determinant of the deformation gradient and $X $ are the lagrangian coordinates. I tried using this but failed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As it says here:

https://books.google.pt/books?id=v_aUAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=why+do+we+postulate+density+to+be+objective&source=bl&ots=oDDTL7L9jE&sig=MvYZMXYRrZN4KqMhKiIt-rQ3PgQ&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZj-f3z_zeAhVlBMAKHQMkDDoQ6AEwAHoECBMQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=true

A zeroth-order tensor is just a real number, so objectivity simply means that this number is the same in all frames of reference.

Since density is not purely kinematic, I think we have to look at the underlying physics.

In here it says the reason we usually assume that is because of Galilean Invariance of the balance laws and physical experiences:

https://books.google.pt/books?id=sOdGCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=why+do+we+postulate+density+to+be+objective&source=bl&ots=nLoVFw2--X&sig=Fzd7qnutvrW1IW601Ysyf9ridkI&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZj-f3z_zeAhVlBMAKHQMkDDoQ6AEwAXoECBIQAQ#v=onepage&q=why%20do%20we%20postulate%20density%20to%20be%20objective&f=false

Not sure if I helped.